# Find end nodes (leaf nodes) in radial (tree) networkx graph

Tags: python, graph-theory, networkx

Given the following graph, is there a convenient way to get only the end nodes?

By end nodes I mean those to-nodes with one connecting edge. I think these are sometimes referred to as leaf nodes.

```
G=nx.DiGraph()
fromnodes=[0,1,1,1,1,1,2,3,4,5,5,5,7,8,9,10]
tonodes=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]
for x,y in zip(fromnodes,tonodes):
    G.add_edge(x,y)
G.add_node(17)     # isolated node
nx.draw_shell(G)
```

[image]

In this example, it would be `[6,11,12,13,14,15,16]`

Comment: Any node not in `fromnodes` would be and end node, no?

Comment: I've given an answer, but there's some ambiguity.  Can you read my answer and then clarify your question?  That way I can remove extraneous things from my answer.  - thanks

Comment: @JohnPirie almost - my question was ambiguous in that it left out a single from-node. I've updated to make clearer.

Comment: @Joel You are correct, thanks. I've updated.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

To make sure the definition is clear: I am assuming you are looking for all nodes which have out-degree 0 and in-degree 1.  This is what my calculations find.

**I'm editing the original answer because networkx 2.0 does not have nodes_iter(). 
 See the networkx [migration guide](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/release/migration_guide_from_1.x_to_2.0.html) in general for turning 1.x code into 2.0 code.**

**for networkx 2.0**

if you want a list

```
[x for x in G.nodes() if G.out_degree(x)==0 and G.in_degree(x)==1]
```

If you'd rather have a generator

```
(x for x in G.nodes() if G.out_degree(x)==0 and G.in_degree(x)==1)
```

This also works in networkx 1.x, but is less efficient because `G.nodes()` creates a list in 1.x.

**for networkx 1.x**

if you want a list

```
[x for x in G.nodes_iter() if G.out_degree(x)==0 and G.in_degree(x)==1]
```

If you'd rather have a generator

```
(x for x in G.nodes_iter() if G.out_degree(x)==0 and G.in_degree(x)==1)
```

and just a note - if you modify `G` while using the generator, the behavior is unlikely to be what you want.

Comment: For a more general purpose leaf node definition I would suggest in_degree > 1. We would like the node to be connected to the graph but leaf nodes may have more than one parent.

Comment: I would like to do this, but I get the following error message: 'Graph' object has no attribute 'out_degree'. Has there been a change in networkx?

Comment: @Takver - you've defined an undirected graph (a `Graph`).  In an undirected graph, you have a degree, not a separate in or out degree.  For `out_degree` to be defined, it will need to be a `DiGraph`.  So either make it a directed graph (if that's appropriate), or switch to `G.degree(x)==1`

Comment: Converting to a directed graph (usingG.to_directed()) results in two edges connecting each pair of nodes. So out_degree will be 1 and in_degree will be >=2 correct? Is it possible to convert to a directed graph with only one edge between each pair of nodes?

Comment: Before converting to a directed graph, we need to ask why you want to do that?  Unless your graph really should be directed, I don't think it's wise to convert it to directed so that you can try some algorithm on it.  What was your goal when you came to this page?